# How to add values in a data frame with specific conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code where it outputs the amount of times a product is bought in a specific month in all stores; however, I was wondering how I would be able to have the sum of 3 conditions, where python would add the products from a specific month and a specific store.

This is my code so far:

```
df = df.groupby(['Month_Bought'])['Amount_Bought'].sum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
01-2020    27
02-2020    26
03-2020    24
04-2020    23
05-2020    31
06-2020    33
07-2020    26
08-2020    30
09-2020    33
10-2020    26
11-2020    30
12-2020    30
```

Need to separate the data to make the dataframe look like this:

```
         Store1   Store2
01-2020    3        24
02-2020    4        22
03-2020    8        16
04-2020    4        19
05-2020    10       21
06-2020    11       21
07-2020    12       14
08-2020    10       20
09-2020    3        30
10-2020    14       12
11-2020    21       9
12-2020    9        21
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: I'm using pandas to read an excel file to use as my data frame.  It looks like this:  
Amount     Agency     Date
`830      WAKEFIELD 11-2020`
`750     CONGRESS 06-2020`
`720     CONGRESS 05-2020`
`5200    WAKEFIELD 04-2020`
`5880    CREEDENCE 01-2020`
`5470    WAKEFIELD 05-2020`
`910      WAKEFIELD 01-2020`
`560      CREEDENCE 07-2020`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is long (a column contains values for which store a product was purchased), you could group by store and month:

```
import pandas as pd
records = [
  {'Month_Bought':'01-2020', 'Amount_Bought':1, 'Store': 'Store1'},
  {'Month_Bought':'01-2020', 'Amount_Bought':2, 'Store': 'Store2'},
  {'Month_Bought':'02-2020', 'Amount_Bought':2, 'Store': 'Store1'},
  {'Month_Bought':'02-2020', 'Amount_Bought':4, 'Store': 'Store2'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)

# Initial dataframe
  Month_Bought  Amount_Bought   Store
0      01-2020              1  Store1
1      01-2020              2  Store2
2      02-2020              2  Store1
3      02-2020              4  Store2

# Now groupby store and month
df_agg = df.groupby(['Store', 'Month_Bought'], as_index=False)['Amount_Bought'].sum()

# Convert from long to wide:
df_agg_pivot = df_agg.pivot(index='Month_Bought', columns='Store', values='Amount_Bought')

# Reformat
df_agg_pivot = df_agg_pivot.reset_index()
df_agg_pivot.columns.name = None

# Final result:
  Month_Bought  Store1  Store2
0      01-2020       1       2
1      02-2020       2       4
```